# javascript YoutubePlayer OnStateChange not firing

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have having issue with youtube player OnStateChange not firing. I have looked at other posts and they don't quite fit into my situation as I am probably using a different (chromeless javascript) version.

HTML:

```
<div id="ytapiplayer">
 You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", wmode: "Opaque" };
var atts = { id: "player" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3",
                   "ytapiplayer", "100%", "100%", "8", null, null, params, atts);

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId){
  player = document.getElementById("player");
}
```

I basically copy the example in the documentation. Then I just do

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');
```

I can get it to work just fine. But the only problem is that when it changes state, the OnStateChange event doesn't fire. The code goes like this.

```
document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('OnStateChange', 
  function(new_state){
     console.log(new_state);
  }
)
```

the new state never got printed out. Am I doing it wrong?  http://jsfiddle.net/8QtrC/1/

Comment: There is no element named player (id="ytapiplayer") as is used in getElementById('player')

Comment: I think the javascript embeds an object(id = "player" as specific in the atts) under "ytapiplayer". I can call all methods on that object(id="player"), but the OnStateChange just never got fired.

Comment: You could be right. Add some code that can be run ?

Comment: I put some codes up on jsfiddle. But the video is not loading. I think jsfiddle might prohibit it.

Comment: I will put a working example in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example works for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/Bl4Qne-RpcM?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=myytplayer&version=3",
                       "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, so that's how that function is used. Awesome.